# Modify ruby hash in place( rails strong params)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This may be more a ruby question then rails question but I'm pretty sure I was able to do this in a vanilla ruby application.

I have strong params defined.

```
def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :date)
end
```

Now I get those params in a controller method.  I want to do this.

```
def save
  trip_params[:name] = 'Modifying name in place'
  #trip_params[:name] still equals original value passed
end
```

This never works.  **Name never changes**. 
BTW: The type of trip_params is ActionController::Parameters

If I do a standard ruby script, it works.

```
test = {}    
test[:name] = "blah"    
test[:name] = "ok"    
puts test #{:name=>"ok"}
```

Comment: Is Trip an active record?  You may need to explicitly save it in the database:  `@trip.save`

Comment: I took the Trip.new part.  Don't let that distract.  I'm trying to modify the ActionController::Parameters hash in place.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`permit` returns a new hash with those keys in it, so you're not modifying the real `params` variable.  You're also not saving a reference to the hash trip_params returns, so you get it fresh each call in `save`.

Try this:

```
def save
  tp = trip_params
  tp[:name] = 'Modifying name in place'
  # ... use tp later, it'll be in there
end
```

Or, if you really want it to be used the way you previously did, modify `trip_params` like so:

```
def trip_params
  @trip_params ||= params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :date)
end
```

Now that hash is lazily cached and the same one is returned on subsequent `trip_params` calls.

Comment: Default values and formatting should be done on the model, though.

Answer (score 30):

If you **really** want to change params in controller you can do it on this way:

```
def save
  params[:trip][:name] = 'Modifying name in place'
  # Now trip_params[:name] is 'Modifying name in place'
end
```

Comment: I think this is the best and simplest answer here. Just modify the actual params first, then call your strong parameters method.

You can even do it with before_action :modify_params, only [:create, :update] then create a private method to keep it out of your create and update methods.

Answer (score 6):

You could also do

```
def save
  data = trip_params.merge(name: 'new name')
  # use data later
end
```

If a new hash is merged into an old hash and if there are duplicate keys, the new hash's keys overwrite the old hash's matching keys.

Answer (score 3):

This is because there's no method such as `trip_params[]=(arg, val).`

I mean, when you call trip_params you are returning the value of `params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :date)`, so every time you call `trip_params` you are getting the params again.

So, if I were you, I'd define the trip_params method as follow:

```
def trip_params
  @trip_params ||= params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :date)
end
```

And would also define a method to change trip_params

```
def trip_params[]= (key,val)
  trip_params # Ensure that trip_params is called once or you will get an error
  @trip_params[key] = val
end
```

So now when you call `trip_params` you would actually return `@trip_params`, and if `@trip_params` is not set yet it would set to `params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :date)`

And then when you call `trip_params[:name] = "Some name"` it will ensure first that `@trip_params` is initialized by calling `trip_params and then it will set the :name param to`"Some name"`

Hope I've helped you