# How to change value in params array in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an instance where I am recording prices for water from vendors. My vendor model has `:price`. However, I want to give users the option to input a price for different volumes, and do the simple division for them rather than having them to do it. In other words, users should be able to input $1.99 per liter or $3.99 for a gallon and so on. To do this, I need a virtual attribute in my form for `:unit`, since I don't want to be storing units in the table. Everything works well, except that I cannot seem to update `vendor_params[:price]` before I update the record or create a new record. This seems like it should be a cake walk, but I Googled most of the day and can't figure out how to make it work.
 Here is what I have:

**Model:**

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :unit
...
end
```

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for(@vendor) do |f| %>
...
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
    <%= select( "unit", "id", { "1 Liter" => "1", "Bottle (2 liters)" => "2", "Jerry Can  (20 liters)" => "20"}) %>
</div>
...
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
...
def update 

vendor_params[:price] = vendor_params[:price].to_f/params[:unit][:id].to_f

respond_to do |format|
  if @vendor.update(vendor_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
...
end
```

I know that `vendor_params[:price].to_f/params[:unit][:id].to_f` returns the correct value. I just can't seem to assign that value to `vendor_params[:price]` before I update the record. I also tried the following which throws an error:

```
@vendor_params[:price] = vendor_params[:price].to_f/params[:unit][:id].to_f
```

It seems like this should be trivial! I guess I could use `form_tag` instead of `form_for`, but that seems odd when updating the full record. (The edit form has all fields for all the object attributes.) Anywho, I'm open to ideas and suggestions.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If vendor_params is a strong_params method (which I'm assuming it is), it actually creates a new hash. So when you alter vendor_params... you're not actually changing your original params hash.

*OK, why isn't vendor_params changing though... I dont care about params?* WELL, vendor_params still points the original params hash assuming it looks something like:

```
def vendor_params
  params.require(:vendor).permit(:price)
end
```

I think the link below is a similar issue and may present a useful solution. Hope I understood your problem correctly!

[Modify ruby hash in place( rails strong params)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369592/modify-ruby-hash-in-place-rails-strong-params)

Comment: Thanks @rsahai91! Your explanation and link gave me an idea how to fix it. I basically created an instance variable like so: `vp = vendor_params` and passed the form hash `vp[:price] = vendor_params[:price].to_f/params[:unit][:id].to_f` then just updated with the instance variable: `@vendor.update(vp)`