# convert rails form data of type string into date

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, date

This may be impossible to do, in this manner. But, in my db schema, I have a field called `anticipated_arrival_date` which is of type `t.date` in my `schema.rb` file.

I am currently using jQuery to grab three disparate `<select>` strings, and concatenate them into a string, representing a date in the following format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`. I do this in the following way:

```
$("#arrival_year").blur(function(){
var month = $('#arrival_month').val();
var day = $('#arrival_day').val();
var year = $('#arrival_year').val();

if (month == "" || day=="" || year==""){
}
else{
  //DD/MM/YYYY
  combined = String(day) + "/" +String(month)+"/"+ String(year); 
  var arrival_date = $('#school_application_anticipated_arrival_date');
  arrival_date.val(combined);
}
});
```

where `#school_application_anctipated_arrival_date` is the `t.date` field on my model which I have made into a `f.hidden_field` in my `<form>`. The problem is that when I submit the form via POST request, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass
if record.anticipated_arrival_date != nil and ((record.start_date <= record.anticipated_arrival_date) or ((record.start_date - record.anticipated_arrival_date).to_i >= 7))
```

which is thrown on my `ancitipated_arrival_date` validation. in short it is saying that `anticipated_arrival_date` is undefined.

Is it A) somehow possible to make a valid `t.date` from a string when `create` is invoked? If not, is there a way, assuming a migrate `anticipated_arrival_date` to a string as opposed to a `date`, that I can make a safe comparison in a validation from `anticipated_arrival_date` to another column which is a real `date` column? For example using `strftime` on the `date` column?

Here is my complete controller file:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f31c26f6c38fe3e21bb

And here is the excerpt of the model file which performs the validations:

```
class AnticipatedArrivalDateValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
 def validate(record)
  if record.anticipated_arrival_date != nil and ((record.start_date <= record.anticipated_arrival_date) or ((record.start_date - record.anticipated_arrival_date).to_i >= 7))
   record.errors[:base] << "Cannot have arrival date be later or equal to start date for Early Night Arrival."
 end
 end
end
```

NOTE: In Reference to comments, I have tried converting the param into a Date via the following `before_action`

```
before_action :cleanup_date_params

def cleanup_date_params
 if params[:school_application]
  anticipated_string  = params[:school_application][:anticipated_arrival_date]
  params[:school_application][:anticipated_arrival_date] = Date.parse(anticipated_string)
  Rails.logger.debug(Date.parse(anticipated_string))
 end
end
```

the problem is that this still results in the error:

```
undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass
```

called on the same line in my Validation.

I think that, the `before_action` is not changing `params[:school_application][:anticipated_arrival_date]` because the `.create` is called on the strong parameter version of `params[:school_application]` and thus must overwrite the params I set in `before_action`. I don't know how to remedy this.

Comment: whats the value of the 'arrival_date' going into params in the controller from the form?

Comment: @Sravan  from my params hash: `"anticipated_arrival_date"=>"05/03/2002",`

Comment: read as March, 5th, 2002

Comment: Then in the controller before creating it, you can change the string to date format using `"05/03/2002".to_date`(param_value.to_date) and then send to create which will check date instead of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the to_date function, to convert the string to date and compare the date in model validation instead of string.

```js
2.1.5 :006 > date = "02/03/2016"
 => "02/03/2016" 
2.1.5 :007 > changed_date = date.to_date
 => Wed, 02 Mar 2016
 
def create
  object = object_params
  object[:date] = object[:date].to_date
  
  /** code of cretae **/
end
```

Then use the validations. [refer to this link](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date)

Comment: but where do I convert it, if I am using strong parameters? confer: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f31c26f6c38fe3e21bb

Comment: AHHHH! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369592/modify-ruby-hash-in-place-rails-strong-params I think i see the light!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
combined = String(day) + "/" +String(month)+"/"+ String(year);
```

To

```
combined = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Rails should handle casting this format to a `date`.

[JS Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I like your approach, Unfortunately I get the same error. Because the paramaters I believe are stringified in the client/server connex: Here is what my `anticipated_arrival_date` turns into using your advice: `"Fri Apr 04 2003 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)"` which looks good. Except it still, when doing the validation renders a `nil` as opposed to a ruby `date`

Comment: Also it looks like this is a `DateTime` in ruby lingo, and not a `Date`

Comment: What does `school_application_params[: anticipated_arrival_date]` output when you put a breakpoint in `def new` or whatever action this is?